# How do i search from various tables with a common unique key and display respective values from each table

Tags: mysql

This is what my tables look like

**Table A**

---

File_ID
Case_Name
Case_Type
Case_Date

**Table B**

---

File_ID
Bill_ID
Bill_Name
Bill_Date

**Table C**

---

Staff_ID
File_ID
Report_ID
Report_Name

**Table D**

---

File_ID
HH_ID
HH_Name
HH_Type

---

How do i collect a similar File_ID from each table and display
Having problems with my statement
My statement reads like this:

```
Connection.open  
SELECT a.CASE_NAME, a.CASE_TYPE, a.CASE_DATE  
FROM TableA a  
WHERE a.FILE_ID = ““  

SELECT b.BILL_ID, b.BILL_NAME, b.BILL_DATE   
FROM TableB b  
WHERE b.FILE_ID = a.FILE_ID  

SELECT c.STAFF_ID, c.REPORT_ID, c.REPORT_NAME  
FROM TableC c  
WHERE c.FILE_ID = b.FILE_ID  

SELECT d.HH_ID, d.HH_TYPE, d.HH_NAME  
FROM TableD d  
WHERE d.FILE_ID = c.FILE_ID  
Connection.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.Case_Name, a.Case_Type, a.Case_Date, 
       b.Bill_ID, b.Bill_Name, b.Bill_Date, 
       c.Staff_ID, c.Report_ID, c.Report_Name, 
       d.HH_ID, d.HH_Name, d.HH_Type

From TableA a
Join TableB b on a.File_ID = b.File_ID
Join TableC c on a.File_ID = c.File_ID
Join TableD d on a.File_ID = d.File_ID
```